# Tikz: even odd rule with intersecting shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I do not know how to use the `even odd rule` to fill intersecting shapes. This is the desired outcome:

[image]

And this is my code. I'd appreciate an explanation of how to apply the `even odd rule`, when to use `clip` and when to use `scope`, which I have seen used in simpler examples of this kind. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}

% define the angle theta = pi/7
\def\theta{25.71}
% define the circle of radius 1
\def\shapeA{(0,0) circle (1cm)}
% define the annulus of radii 1 and 2
\def\shapeB{(0,0) circle (1cm) (0,0) circle (2cm)}
% define the annulus of radii 2 and 3
\def\shapeC{(0,0) circle (2cm) (0,0) circle (3cm)}
% define the intersecting lines
% attempted to group them for even-odd rule
%\def\shapeD{(180+\theta:3.5cm) -- (0,0) -- (\theta:3.5cm)}
%\def\shapeE{(-\theta:3.5cm) -- (0,0) -- (180-\theta:3.5cm)}
\def\shapeD{(-\theta:3.5cm) -- (0,0) -- (\theta:3.5cm)}
\def\shapeE{(180+\theta:3.5cm) -- (0,0) -- (180-\theta:3.5cm)}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \fill[fill=lightgray, even odd rule]  \shapeE \shapeB;
  \fill[fill=lightgray, even odd rule]  \shapeD \shapeA;
  \draw \shapeA \shapeB \shapeC \shapeD \shapeE;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Comment in passing: the angle needed to replicate the figure was half of what I used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You complicated too much.

[image: even odd rule on multiple shapes]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}

% define the angle theta = pi/7
\def\theta{25.71}
\def\shapeA{(0,0) circle (1cm)}
\def\shapeB{(0,0) circle (2cm)}
\def\shapeC{(0,0) circle (3cm)}

\def\shapeD{(-\theta:3.5cm) -- (0,0) -- (\theta:3.5cm)}
\def\shapeE{(180+\theta:3.5cm) -- (0,0) -- (180-\theta:3.5cm)}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \shapeC;
        \fill[fill=lightgray, even odd rule]  \shapeE \shapeB \shapeD \shapeA;
    \end{scope}
  
  \draw \shapeA \shapeB \shapeC \shapeD \shapeE;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Just declare all your shapes, in a simple way (here, for example, the circles needed to be declared as they are, not as annuli like you tried to). Then fill with `even odd rule`  all the shapes together.

As for the `\clip`, here you don't want to fill outside the larger circle, so you `scope` the filling with a `\clip \shapeC;`, meaning that, inside your `scope` environment, nothing is drawn outside *shapeC*. And you finally draw your lines outside the `scope` environment to let them be drawn outside the larger circle.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is already a nice and accepted answer, I feel free to add a solution using `nofill` and `eofill` from MetaPost/MetaFun. Mostly for fun, but I hope someone could have a use for it! The file is compiled with `context`.

```
\startMPpage[offset=3bp]
u:=1cm;

path circle[],line[];

for i=0 upto 2:
circle[i] = fullcircle scaled (2(i+1)*u);
endfor

line0 = ((-1,0)--(1,0)) rotated 360/28 scaled 4u;
line1 = line0 rotated (180-360/14);

nofill circle1;
nofill line0 -- line1 -- cycle;
eofill circle0 withcolor lightgray;
clip currentpicture to circle2;

for i=circle0,circle1,circle2,line0,line1:
draw i;
endfor
\stopMPpage
```

The result shows as follows:

[image: Result, which looks like the image in the question]

Comment: I don't use Metapost yet, but I'm always amazed by the simplicity of the syntax and the beauty of the results. Thanks for this one.

Comment: Thanks mickep, always nice to have options! :-)